# Repeating background in iOS when set to no-repeat

Tags: ios, css, iphone, background-image

I have an issue on a website I did a few years ago. It repeats the background on iOS. 
The URL is [writersadvice.co.uk](http://www.writersadvice.co.uk)

[image: iPhone repeating background problem]

I don't have an iPhone myself and can't iOS simulator to work on my macbook but if anyone has any ideas, would be great as I have searched and not found any clues so far.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep your site as it is? There are better techniques than having a 994x10000 background image, my iPhone refuses to even download the image, let alone show it twice. Other than that, I think you should check your code a few times over and fix double styles like `.cssbox { width: 980px !important; width: 965px; .. }`

Comment: I did the site a long time ago, before the dawn of smartphones.. that repeated style you quote there was an IE hack.
Yes there may well be better ways to have an extending vertical background like that.. the file size is still fairly small as it is mostly whitespace. I don't have a lot of time spare to redo the site, so would rather keep it close to how it is now. Ideally, yes it would be redone with proper responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your site and on a iPad and it did load the double background, opened through Safari on the PC to see if it happened as well but no luck there. A wild guess was it being the retina vs normal screen, which it happened to be.

A quick fix would be to add the following to your CSS, below all the other background calls:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){
  .cssbox, .cssbox_body, .cssbox_head, .cssbox_head h2 {
      background-size: 1988px 20000px;
  }
}
```

But it ain't pretty, I'd really spend a few minutes re-writing some when possible ;)